# Cannot create new file (newfile.txt) using php

Tags: php

I am starting to learn php, I want to create and write a simple text file. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Name
$filename = "newfile.txt";
//Pointer
$file = fopen( $filename, "w" );
if( $file == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
//Write the data
fwrite( $file, "This is  a simple test\n" );
fclose( $file );
?>
```

When I run the script it returns the error: "Error opening new file", have no idea why it's doing this. I know the file doesn't exist yet, but from what I understand the option w should create a new file if it doesn't exist. Could someone give some pointers on what I might be doing wrong please?

EDIT:

It seems my permissions aren't set correctly on my APACHE server. I just tried this:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite 
chmod -R og-r /var/www/mysite
```

Now I can't even access the directory and check the contents! In the terminal I just get "Permission denied"

Comment: try making the file name a directory using `/newfile.txt'

Comment: Just tried that, still showing the error

Comment: if its not working then it means php don't have access to write files in your system

Comment: Try with `fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");`

Comment: @Saty No difference there

Comment: It means you are not able to create file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite 
chmod -R 755 /var/www/mysite
```

will give you access and allow you to write (and read)

Answer (score 2):

Change the permission of file before opening it to read or write.

```
<?php
//Name
$filename = "newfile.txt";
//change permission of file
chmod($filename,0777);
//Pointer
$file = fopen( $filename, "w" );
if( $file == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
//Write the data
fwrite( $file, "This is  a simple test\n" );
fclose( $file );
?>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but the explanation is a bit short: Basicly your server is setup in a way that php is not allowed to make new files. depending on the server you use you can can change that yourself (with what the answer contains) or you need to ask the server admin, if he can change the settings for you.

Comment: I am not creating a new file with this code (with what your comment says) . It is changing the permission.

Comment: I have access to the server, it's a LAMP I setup

Comment: @DocRattie I don't know why you down-voted without knowing that whether  the user has access to server or not.

Comment: @varunsinghal it wasn't me that downvoted your answer. I just wrote the comment to add some clerefication.

Comment: @DocRattie okay sorry for that.

Comment: do you have filezilla?